# Cannot authenticate: HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

**The Goal**: I'd like to allow the user to access any page on my webapp, except for the `/account` page (unless they're logged in). I'd like this logging in process to be quite secure, and therefore have turned to using Spring Security in conjunction with the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to handle this process. This webapp is being developed using Spring's *pure-Java approach* (no xml configurations whatsoever).

**What Works**: Going to `/account` correctly redirects the user to the `/login` page. The user can also correctly go to the `/` page without being redirected.

**The Problem**: I'm trying to configure Spring Security with my own custom `UserDetailsService`, but whenever I attempt to log in through the form on my JSP view, the `loadUserByUsername(String username)` method that I overwrote in said `UserDetailsService` does not appear to be called. In addition, it seems that when the user logs in with *supposedly* valid credentials, their authentication is not being stored in the Spring Security's current session and instead remain `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`.

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/css/**")
                .antMatchers("/js/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/account").hasAnyRole("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

        http
            .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/loginfailed")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsService:**

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        username = username.toLowerCase();
        try
        {
            Account account = testAccount(); // See below for more details
            if(account == null)
            {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user '" + username + "' in the database.");
            }

            List<GrantedAuthority> auths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            for(Role r : account.getRoles())
            {
                auths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.getRole()));
            }

            WebUser user = null;
            try
            {
                user = new WebUser(account.getUserID(), username, account.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, auths);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return user;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " not found", e);
        }
    }

    private Account testAccount()
    {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.setUserID(1);
        acc.setUsername("admin");
        acc.setPassword("$2a$10$ETHSfGAR8FpNTyO52O7qKuoo2/8Uqdwcqq70/5PN4.8DXTR6Ktiha");
        acc.setDescription("No description.");
        acc.setInfluence(9001);
        acc.setJoinDate("03-15-2014");
        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
        roles.add(new Role(Role.ADMIN)); // Role.ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN"
        roles.add(new Role(Role.USER)); // Role.USER = "ROLE_USER"
        return acc;
    }
}
```

**login.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <base href="${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="document.loginForm.j_username.focus();">
    <div id="page_wrap">
        <h2><a href="">Login Page</a></h2>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="login">
                <form name="loginForm" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method="POST">
                    <h5>Log in to your account</h5>
                    <p>
                        <label for="name">Username: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="j_username" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="name">Password: </label>
                        <input type="password" name="j_password" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log In" name="submit" />
                    </p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                </form>

                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                    <div class="errorblock">
                        Your login attempt was not successful, please try again.<br>
                        Caused: ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
                    </div>
                </c:if>

            </div><!--end login-->
        </div><!--end container-->
    </div><!--end page_wrap-->

</body>
</html>
```

**The Input:**

Username Input Field ("j_username") : admin
Password Input Field ("j_password") : password
*Note: The hashed password I use in UserDetailsServiceImpl was generated using* `bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("password");`

**The Results:**
Remains on the `/login` page, does not redirect to `/` as it should on a successful login.

**The Output:**

```
12726 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
12726 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@66201d6d. A new one will be created.
...
12727 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /j_spring_security_check; Attributes: [authenticated]
12727 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faeba70: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffbcba8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 9626C55509CC1073AC2B5A8F65B2A585; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
12728 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased  - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@14cef147, returned: -1
12728 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the log it looks like you are hitting an access denied on                 "/j_spring_security_check". That's understandable because you didn't mark it as unprotected. I think you may just be making a false assumption about the default login processing URL (/login with `@Configuration` iirc). If you post to "/login" instead does it work?